# Typescript typeorm: how to get annotation parameters

Tags: typescript, typeorm, typescript-decorator

we use typeorm in our projects and have entities like that:

```
@Entity({ name: 'contacts', database: Schemas.interfax75 })
export class OutgoingLog {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ name: 'TransactionID' })
    transactionId: number;
    @Column({ name: 'SubmitTime', type: 'datetime', default: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' })
    submitTime: Date;
    // more properties here
}
```

I want to get the name attribute of the annotation. So, knowing the property name `transactionId` I want to get the string `TransactionID`. Is it possible to do it in typescript?

I know there's package `reflect-metadata`, but it has quite poor documentation and I can't really understand if it's possible to do with it or not.

That's the generated js code.

```
var __decorate = (this && this.__decorate) || function (decorators, target, key, desc) {
    var c = arguments.length, r = c < 3 ? target : desc === null ? desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key) : desc, d;
    if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.decorate === "function") r = Reflect.decorate(decorators, target, key, desc);
    else for (var i = decorators.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (d = decorators[i]) r = (c < 3 ? d(r) : c > 3 ? d(target, key, r) : d(target, key)) || r;
    return c > 3 && r && Object.defineProperty(target, key, r), r;
};

//...
__decorate([
    typeorm_1.PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ name: 'TransactionID' }),
    __metadata("design:type", Number)
], OutgoingLog.prototype, "transactionId", void 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use TypeORM API

```
getConnection()
  .getMetadata(OutgoingLog)
  .ownColumns
  .map(column => {
    // Do what you want with column
    // For example, log it into console
    // And check all fields — `properyName` and others
    console.log(column)
  })
```

Source of my advice — https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1764

Comment: thanks, but it uses the connection object and, as per my understanding, will pull that data from the db. Please correct me if I'm wrong and it won't make a network request.

Comment: If you execute DB-query, it doen't require any network request, actually.